# Need help understanding <p:inputNumber/> with <p:ajax/>

Tags: primefaces

I have a Primefaces question that I am having a lot of trouble finding a solution. I have search the Primefaces documentation with no luck.

We are using Primefaces 6.0

I have two `<p:inputNumber/>` and I want to sum the value of both of them and display in real-time on the screen while the user is typing. My ajax call inside each inputNumber is :

```
<p:ajax update="totalcount" listener="#{myBean.updateTotalCount()}"/>
```

everything almost works as expected. However totalcount is only updated when focus is lost on the two inputNumber boxes.

I would like for total to be triggered while the user is typing. I have tried to look up the Primefaces documentation and I thought something like

```
<p:ajax event="change" update="totalcount" listener="#{myBean.updateTotalCount()}"/>
```

would be sufficient but the ajax fails to trigger altogether.

I am not sure if I am just looking in the wrong place or if inputNumber is different from inputText and so not all ajax events are available to me or what.

any sugguestions?

EDIT: added code snippets:

XHTML:

```
<p:outputPanel id="totalcount">TOTAL COUNT : #{myBean.totalCount}%</p:outputPanel>

<p:inputNumber size="3" id="one" value="#{myBean.one}">
         <p:ajax update="totalcount" listener="#{myBean.updateTotalCount()}"/>
</p:inputNumber>
<p:inputNumber size="3" id="two" value="#{myBean.two}">
         <p:ajax update="totalcount" listener="#{myBean.updateTotalCount()}"/>
</p:inputNumber>
```

BEAN:

```
int one;
int two;
int totalcount;
...getter and setters here...

public void updateTotalCount() throws Exception {
     total = one + two;
}
```

With the code above only when the two inputNumber boxes lose focus will the total be calculated. If I add event="keyup" to both then the AJAX no longer triggers at all. Adding the process attribute does not seem to affect my results in anyway good or bad.

Comment: Have you tried using p:remoteCommand to call the updateTotalCount method and calling it via javascript using onkeyup? in the remoteCommand tag add process="@form" so that all the input elements in the form are submitted.

Comment: @Max: there is totally no need for this 'complex' woraround. See the answer...

Comment: Tried 6.1? Just to see if something was fixed

Answer (score 2):

Try use atributes event="keyup" and proccess="@this, secondInputNumberId"

Comment: I'm afraid this did not help me. based on my debugging code adding the event="keyup" in the ajax tag totally disabled the ajax from triggering. removing event="keyup" again makes the code work but only when the box looses focus. 

the process attribute does not seem to affect things good or bad.

Comment: did you added an the proccess attribute ?